# Many WMQ amqrmppa processes

Tags: ibm-mq

I am running WebSphere MQ v7.1.0.1 under Linux. Is it normal to see too many amqrmppa processes for the same Queue Manager?

```
mqm       3504  1745  2 Nov01 ?        03:40:23 /opt/mqm/bin/amqrmppa -m TEST
mqm       4804  1745  0 08:56 ?        00:01:21 /opt/mqm/bin/amqrmppa -m TEST
mqm       5022  1745 27 08:56 ?        01:17:32 /opt/mqm/bin/amqrmppa -m TEST
mqm       5944  1745 27 09:30 ?        01:07:45 /opt/mqm/bin/amqrmppa -m TEST
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal.  `amqrrmpa` is the channel pooling process.  When WMQ used `inetd` you would see one process per channel instance. Then it was changed to stand-alone listeners and there were only so many child processes you could run per listener.  The new model uses `amqrrmpa` to pool channels and it will dynamically spawn or kill processes as needed, depending on load.  Do not expect it to kill them quickly if you shut down all your channels, though.  It will kill unused `amqrrmpa` instances if resources get low, otherwise it assumes 'you needed this many before, you'll probably need this many again' and lets them hang around a while.

Comment: Thanks!  Did you notice the synonyms are fixed?  The ibm-mq and mqseries tags  now merge to websphere-mq.  W00t!